# How to programmatically access Orchard Modules from outside?

Tags: orchardcms

Can I use any Orchard module in my existing project just be giving reference to Orchard module DLL directly (e.g. if I have to use Roles or Themes or Widgets modules)?

Answer (score 2):

No, that won't work. The simplest approach is probably to expose what you need from Orchard through web services and consume that from the other site.

Comment: He Roy, Thanks for the answer...But in that case the Orchard site should be running somewhere, Right?...My requirement is that I want to use say themes and widget module in my project as a plug-in to achieve the same functionality that these modules are designed for. So can I do that just by adding them to my project? Or they have a dependency on other orchard modules.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, but as Orchard is Open Source you can borrow sections of code.

In a project recently I used the permission system in Orchard as inspiration for my approach to the problem. I wasn't able to just use the Orchard code directly, but I found it a great starting point.